# Finding set range/ intervals given start&end times (data.table package)

Tags: r

I am trying to create time intervals for each data row given the start and end times. For example given the start/end times I would like to create the respective time range shown in another column [the right column] called 'time range'. The goal is to divide the day into quarters of (0-6:00,6-12:00,12-18:00,18-24:00).

```
Person        Start Time            End Time            Time range
A             4/22/2018 8:58        4/22/2018 9:07      6:00-11:59 
B             4/19/2018 6:14        4/19/2018 6:20      6:00-11:59
C             4/18/2018 21:41       4/18/2018 22:03     18:00-23:59
```

I am using `"data.table" package` and upload the csv file using               `file1 <- fread("Data.csv",sep = ",")` since the file can be very large and I heard that it is better to use data.table for faster computation; however, I am having trouble stripping the start and end times to create the time ranges. For this purpose only the start time matters.   Thanks

Comment: Please refrain from using the RStudio tag unless you have a problem specifically with rstudio.

Comment: What should happen when the interval extends to more than one range? E.g. interval `4/18/2018 21:41 - 4/19/2018 04:49`

Comment: in order to get good answers you could do the following:
save the first three rows of your data.table in a seperate object x, select the relevant columns of x and then post the output of dput(x).

Comment: for this purpose only start time matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know your date format so I created it as POSIXct. It's a base R solution, not `data.table`.

```
# sample data
df <- data.frame(Person = LETTERS[1:5], 
            start_time = as.POSIXct(c("4/22/2018 8:58", "4/19/2018 6:14", 
                         "4/18/2018 21:41", '5/17/2018 00:00', '7/17/2018 17:59'), 
                                    format = '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M'))

# extract hour from start_time and identify corresponding interval by dividing by 6
interval_id <- as.numeric(format(df$start_time, "%H")) %/% 6

# prepare and add time ranges
df$range <- c("00:00-05:59", "06:00-11:59", '12:00-17:59', '18:00-23-59')[interval_id+1]

#  Person          start_time       range
#1      A 2018-04-22 08:58:00 06:00-11:59
#2      B 2018-04-19 06:14:00 06:00-11:59
#3      C 2018-04-18 21:41:00 18:00-23-59
#4      D 2018-05-17 00:00:00 00:00-05:59
#5      E 2018-07-17 17:59:00 12:00-17:59
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use data.table to import csv and then the package `lubridate` for date/time manipulation. Probably you should also state that you have columns with date variables with `yourdf$Start_Time<-as.Date(x,...)`.
If you still have some problems let me know how I can help you.

Comment: can `as.Date()` be used to strip time? I search and it said its only for dates. If so how should I do it that is most optimal because the code should run very fast given a very large dataset.

Comment: try like this `require(lubridate)
var1 <- mdy_hms("07-24-2017 09:55:26")`